# Polynomial ring is not a UFD

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $K$ be a field, and consider the ring $R=\{f\in K[x]\mid f'(1)=f''(1)=0\}$. Show that $R$ is not a UFD (Unique Factorization Domain).

**My thoughts:** I can show that elements such as $(x-1)^3$ and $(x-1)^4$ are irreducible in $R$. Can this be used to show $R$ is not a UFD? I am not sure the best route to take. Should we exhibit an element with a non-unique factorization into irreducibles, or should we find two elements who do not have a GCD? Another thing we may be able to do, is consider a quotient of $R$ by an irreducible polynomial and show it has zero-divisors (hence it is not a domain, so the polynomial we choose isn't prime, but every irreducible polynomial in a UFD must be prime).

Comment: An element with non-unique factorisation is easiest, methinks.

Comment: IF you knew $z^3$ and $z^4$ were irreducible, then you would have no trouble coming up with inequivalent factorizations of $z^{12}$.

Answer (score 3):

Silly me. Following the advice of @rschwieb, we have the non-unique factorizations
$$
(x-1)^{12}=(x-1)^3(x-1)^3(x-1)^3(x-1)^3
$$
and
$$
(x-1)^{12}=(x-1)^4(x-1)^4(x-1)^4
$$
into irreducibles. Therefore $R$ is not a UFD. Just to add this bit of detail: $(x-1)^3$ and $(x-1)^4$ are irreducible in $R$ since if they weren't, they'd either have a linear or quadratic factor. But any linear or quadratic factor will either have a non-zero constant first or second derivative, violating the definition of $R$.